# chaining promise (bluebird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I am using nodeJs and bluebird. i have methode to check for parameters validity, so i create a module where i have (see code below) and all of them are promises.

```
exports.validateSpeciality = validateSpeciality;
exports.validateGovernorate = validateGovernorate;
exports.validateCities = validateCities;
```

In my controller (see code below) i always get the first promise result in the then containing "res.send(results)"

```
validator
.validateSpeciality(speciality)
.then(validator.validateGovernorate(governorate))
.then(validator.validateCities(governorate, cities))
.then(Doctor.searchBySpecialityAndByCities(speciality, cities))
.then(function (results) {
  console.log(results);
  res.send(results);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(400).send(error);
})
```

Can someone explain to me why it is not working in this way? even if one of the promise is rejected it always execute the last then and don't go to catch.

Comment: promise `then` take a function, not a promise as argument.

Comment: To add to @KaiHao's comment - if you want to chain promises like that, you need to pass a function that *returns* a promise to `.then`.

Comment: okay i see so the solution will be then(function() { call_my_function })

Comment: You should be seeing a warning in the console from bluebird telling you exactly what the problem is - are you not seeing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently in your Promise chain, you don't use the results of the previous function calls. You run the next promise, when the previous was not resolved. So, even one of the functions: `validateGovernorate`, `validateCities`, `searchBySpecialityAndByCities` rejected with error, the final `then` will be called anycase.

To fix that, run the next function, when the previous promise is resolved:

```
validator
 .validateSpeciality(speciality)
 .then(function() {
    return validator.validateGovernorate(governorate);
 })
 .then(function() {
    return validator.validateCities(governorate, cities);
 });
 .then(function() {
    return Doctor.searchBySpecialityAndByCities(speciality, cities);
 })
 .then(function(results) {
   console.log(results);
   res.send(results);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(400).send(error);
});
```

Also, check that you haven't `catch` blocks in all the functions: `validateGovernorate`, `validateCities`, `searchBySpecialityAndByCities`. And if you have throw an error there or reject with error.

Check [this article](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) there is very good desribed how promises work.